# How to apply conditional formatting to multiple rows based on if a cell is empty in each row?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a sheet so that as a value is entered into each row of a specific column, that row would highlight. I'm able to do it for a single row using the formula `=not(isblank($C3))`, but then I can't copy that conditional formatting to the other rows since it's using an absolute reference. If I try using just `=not(isblank(C3))` then only the first cell in the row ends up being formatted.

Here's an example of what I'm looking to do. As values are added to column C, the entire row would highlight.

[image]

Comment: Did you apply that formatting to the whole range? something like A2:C?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Conditional formatting rule.
- Set the Range as A2:C
- Select "Custom formula"

  - `=NOT(ISBLANK($C2:$C))`

---

**Sample**

[image: sample]